# Cordova fail when try to build Android app with error "Command failed with exit code 2" Linux

Tags: android, linux, bash, cordova

I'm using Ubuntu Gnome 14.04 64 Bit (for the moment) with kernel 3.19.0-33-generic.

I created a new app (a clean one, no plugin, no www folder with content) to try to build it.
After type in the bash "cordova build android"
I get this error:

```
Running command: /home/aby/Desktop/testApp/platforms/android/cordova/build 
[Error: Android SDK not found. Make sure that it is installed. If it is not at the default location, set the ANDROID_HOME environment variable.]
ERROR building one of the platforms: Error:/home/aby/Desktop/testApp/platforms/android/cordova/build: Command failed with exit code 2
You may not have the required environment or OS to build this project
Error: /home/aby/Desktop/testApp/platforms/android/cordova/build: Command failed with exit code 2
```

Now if you `printenv | grep android`

You will get

```
ANDROID_HOME=/opt/android-sdk-linux
ANDROID_PLATFORM_TOOLS=/opt/android-sdk-linux/platform-tools
PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/opt/android-sdk-linux/tools:/opt/android-sdk-linux/platform-tools:/opt/android-sdk-linux/tools:/opt/android-sdk-linux/platform-tools:/home/aby/bin:/home/aby/opt/jdk8/jdk1.8.0_45/bin:/opt/android-sdk-linux/tools:/opt/android-sdk-linux/platform-tools:/opt/android-sdk-linux/tools:/opt/android-sdk-linux/platform-tools
ANDROID_SDK=/opt/android-sdk-linux
```

You can see that the variables exist, in fact before I run `cordova build android` I had to use `cordova platform add android` and its works with no problem.

So I found this [Bug](https://github.com/driftyco/ionic-cli/issues/282), and tried some solution like update android(project) or remove and install it again with no success.

I reinstall the Andoroid SDK, and updated the "/.bashrc", "/.profile" and "~/.pam_enviroment" with the environment values and also this not help.

So how can I fix this? How can I build my app with no error? What I missing?(If you consider that you need another information please tell me).

Thanks, in advance.

Comment: I have never tried building without having anything inside `www/`. Maybe try creating a standard `www/index.html` and seeing if it can build on the phongap cloud. If it builds on phonegap cloud then try to build locally once more. Another suggestion would be to check your version of cordova. Might be that you using a version of cordova incompatible with the Android SDK you have.

Comment: I have the same error with other project with stuff inside www. My cordova version is 5.4.0.

Comment: What about saying `ANDROID_HOME=/opt/android-sdk-linux cordova build android`?

Comment: No works, any way I think I could fix this problem changing my permissions of android-sdk/tools/android.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the end I could fix my problem when I change the "Owner" / "Group" to the android sdk folder and Permission to "/tools/android".

[Here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/696601/sudo-android-return-sudo-android-command-not-found/696617?noredirect=1#comment1019346_696617) a link to my previous question, and the solution (at least for me) to fix this error.